# ocserv failed to handshake

Tags: networking, server, ssl

I deployed ocserv 1.1.3 and when try to connwct I got following error:

Attempting to connect to server X.Y.Z.W:443
Connected to X.Y.Z.W:443
SSL negotiation with domain.xyz
SSL connection failure: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Failed to open HTTPS connection to domain.xyz
Failed to complete authentication

how can resolve the issue??

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 22.04